# ASP.NET Core MVCと.NET Framework Formアプリケーションでのプロセス間通信

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core MVC（3.1）より、同一PC内の.NET Framework（4.8） Fromアプリケーションの機能を利用したいと考えています。
この場合、プロセス間通信が必要になると思いますが、パフォーマンスを最大化するにはどういった方法を用いるのが適切でしょうか？

できれば非同期処理が可能な方法の中で適切な方法を探しています。

Comment: 質問内容が曖昧だったり範囲が広かったりして[買い物リスト問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/26370)のようにも見えます。もう少し要件/要求事項や評価軸が具体化していたり優先順位が明確化していると助言や回答が付きやすいのでは？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プロセス間通信にはいくつも方法があるようですが、
.NET Frameworkと.NET Coreで共通で使える方法が必要です。

- .Netリモーティング（System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc）：.NET Coreになし
- Windows Communication Foundation（WCF）：.NET Coreになし？
- 匿名パイプ
- 名前付きパイプ
- ・・・・

匿名パイプではForm Applicationの配置に関して制限がありそうでした。

Form Applicationをパフォーマンスの要求されるサーバーとして利用するには、
複数スレッドでの待ち受け、非同期の読み書きも考慮している名前付きパイプが適切と判断しました。

下記２サイトを参照し、名前付きパイプサーバーを実装しました。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication
https://ichiroku11.hatenablog.jp/entry/2016/08/03/225606